Form.io react icons not working as expected
Icons on the Form.io forms are not rendering properly in the React application. The expected Font Awesome icons are either missing or not displaying as intended, which affects the user interface and experience.

Below are the imports for Form.io component used in .scss

@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"; 
@import "formiojs/dist/formio.full.min.css"; 
@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css';

Package.json
"@formio/react": "^5.3.0-rc.3"
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.2"
"formiojs": "^4.19.3"


@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css']  what does ( ] ) do at the end of import?

Apologies, I just edited it. it's ;

Here is the link more detailed - https://github.com/formio/react/issues/573
